# Is there any reason to get a United Club subscription rather than the United Club card?

Tags: payment-cards, united-airlines, lounges

I travel a lot and I'm looking at getting a United Club membership. What I'm wondering is -- is there any advantage at all to buying a membership rather than getting the credit card?

A membership is $500 for one person, or $750 for one person and a spouse. The club card costs $395, comes with a United Club membership which automatically allows traveling companions to join you, and has other perks like free checked bags.

The card seems to be a better deal in every day, so why does the normal membership exist? Is it just there for people with bad credit or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in both United Club membership and holding a United mileage credit card, by all means go for the United Club card. But everyone isn't necessarily like you.

- Some people aren't interested in holding an additional credit card, or can't qualify for an additional credit card, or can't qualify for this particular card, but are still interested in United Club membership.
- Some people don't want another card, but also don't mind the higher membership fee because they pay for Club membership with miles.
- Some people don't want another card, but also don't mind the higher membership fee because they are reimbursed for membership through their employer or other organization.
- Some people don't want another card, but also don't mind the membership fee because it is discounted on account of their frequent flyer status.
- United frequent flyer elites already receive the non-Club benefits of the card such as a free checked baggage allowance and priority boarding, so Premiers and GS gain nothing from the card in terms of travel privileges except for Club membership.

All the U.S. carriers are heavily dependent on their affiliated credit cards for revenue, so it is unsurprising that United finds the idea of gaining another cardholder more desirable than a mere hundred dollars of annual revenue. The time may come when that is no longer the case, and the annual card fee and the annual club membership fee may fall closer together in price, but the option to join the club without holding the credit card is not likely to go away.

(Note that the United Club membership provided through the card is a regular United Club membership. There is no special tier of membership just for credit card holders; you are not entitled to any benefits beyond an ordinary Club membership. You are entitled to same number of guests as well: 2 adults, or 1 adult with any dependent children, not an unlimited number of traveling companions.)

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought about paying for the membership with miles, and I didn't notice that all United Club memberships allow traveling companions too. As far as I can tell, the frequent flier discount doesn't change the situation though, since even 1K members have to pay $400 for a membership, but could get a card for $395 (although with a $5 difference, the inconvenience of a credit card that you don't want might not be worth it).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly note that United Club membership also allows up to 2 guests - same as the United Club Card.  The higher 'plus Spouse' rate means that you both get a card, and thus can both enter when travelling separately.  The price you've stated is also only correct for someone without any status in United's Mileage Plus program - the higher your status, the lower the price. (eg, as a 1K, my UC membership only costs $400/year)

In general, the only different between the two methods of access is that the United Club Card is a credit card, and thus requires you to apply for it, and sustain the impact that such an application will have on your credit score. Obviously if your credit score isn't high enough it's also possible that you'll be rejected.

United Club membership on the other hand is just a simple payment. No impact on credit score, no chance of being rejected, etc.

Comment: The club membership is also available to people who aren't US residents, and so who otherwise wouldn't be able to apply for a US credit card

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't noticed that the two guest thing was the same for both. It looks like you can pay the extra $250 for a spouse card either way though (under ["Offer Details"](https://creditcards.chase.com/credit-cards/united-club-credit-card.aspx): "Cardmembers may purchase a United Club spouse membership by calling the United Club Service Center").